# AR representation without 3rd party apps

Tags: camera, augmented-reality

I have stuck on very interesting question in regards of the AR. Is there a way to represent an augmented reality 3d objective with a camera application by apple without downloading any of the 3rd party apps. just by pointing it towards the camera

Comment: Can you give some more inputs, are you expecting rendering of 3D models by using default Camera application , instead of using AR based application developed using ARKit by apple

Comment: exactly that's exactly what I am looking towards to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AR applications uses ARKit which enables world tracking which works through a technique called visual-inertial odometry.
By using the iPhone or iPad’s camera and motion sensors, ARKit will find bunch of points in the environment and track them when you move the phone. Once you pin it in the real world 3D model is rendered.
Where as these operations are not supported by the default camera application since they are not leveraging ARKit internally by Default.